# Using multiple jquery version libraries

Tags: jquery

I have a slider and a navigation bar, both requires the use of different jquery version.

The slider uses 1.7.2 while the navigation uses 1.4.2

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var $jq = $.noConflict(true);
    </script>

<!-- NAVIGATION -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $jq(document).ready(function() {
        $jq('#main-image-box').children().removeClass('facets').end().facets({
            control: 'ul#mainlevel',
            clipSpacing: 1,
            animationSpeed: 400,
            beforeMax: function(index) {
                $('#main-image-box .clip:eq('+index+') .container').show();
            },
            beforeMin: function(index) {
                $('#main-image-box .clip:eq('+index+') .container').hide();
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

<!-- SLIDER -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

       (window).load(function(){
            ('#slider').nivoSlider();
        });
        </script>
```

As you can see, I have tried using noconflict but it doesn't work, how do I solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using two jQuery libraries 1.7.1.js and 1.5.2.js on a facebook app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235107/using-two-jquery-libraries-1-7-1-js-and-1-5-2-js-on-a-facebook-app)

Comment: In you navigation code you use both `$jq` and `$`, in the slider code you forget the `$`

Comment: This is why you should learn to write jquery instead of relying on plugins. And if you are going to rely on plugins pick ones under active development.

Answer (score 2):

Does the navigation *require* 1.4.2?? I'd be surprised if it did.

So just get rid of that older version, and try it out.

Comment: More a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
var $jVersion7 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $jVersion4 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Note that, if the navigation plugin you use **MUST use jQuery 1.4.2 ONLY**, it will be a good idea to choose a new plugin and dispose the old version.

jQuery has lots of plugins.

Comment: It works even if I use the 1.72 but if I uses on IE, navigation seems to be buggy.

Comment: @user1631889. so go get yourself a new plugin. this is what I would do. in the meanwhile, my code above should do the job.

Comment: I wishes to get a new plugin, but due to company requirements, I can't get new plugin. Is there any alternatives?

Comment: @user1631889. Yes! **MY ANSWER...** :)

Comment: ==, I will try find another way around, kinda hard to find a plugin with same version or older ==

Comment: @user1631889. Dude! are you real? my code in the answer does what you want! it will  give you two different jQuery versions instances.

Comment: I tried the solution you gave, it doesn't work I don't know why. Anyway, I found another slider that has almost the same function as this slider and uses the older version of jquery.